# split stereo audio to mono streams on iOS

Tags: objective-c, audio, core-audio

Apologies if this has been answered. I've seen lots of questions but no good answers.

I'm trying to export stereo music from my iPod library to two mono caf files. How can I do this on iOS? I'm currently using Objective C.

Thanks!

Update: I've managed to get the sample code working from apple thats here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_Export.html

My code will now import a media file and output as a valid caf file which plays fine. My problem is I can't work out how to modify the buffer before writing it. Here is my code I have so far:

```
// Get the next audio sample buffer, and append it to the output file.
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [self.assetReaderAudioOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
if (sampleBuffer != NULL)
{
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
    AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
    NSMutableData *data= [NSMutableData data];

    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(AudioBufferList), NULL, NULL, kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment, &blockBuffer);

    AudioBuffer audioBuffer = audioBufferList.mBuffers[0];

    for( int y=0; y< audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; y=y+4 ){
        [data appendBytes:(audioBuffer.mData+y) length:2];
    }

    // how do I replace data in sampleBuffer with new data?

    CFRelease(blockBuffer);

    //////////////////////////////////////////

    BOOL success = [self.assetWriterAudioInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

    CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    sampleBuffer = NULL;
    completedOrFailed = !success;
}
else
{
    completedOrFailed = YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your current export code so we can see what type of assets you're using for the current export?

Comment: Have you verified by looking at the bytes of the written file that the header is correct?

Comment: I haven't. Is this how you do that? hexdump -x monoleft.caf 

0000000    6163    6666    0100    0000    6564    6373    0000    0000
0000010    0000    2000    e540    8088    0000    0000    0000    0000
0000020    0000    0c00    0000    0200    0000    0100    0000    0200
0000030    0000    1000    7266    6565    0000    0000    0000    b00f
0000040    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000
*
0000ff0    6164    6174    0000    0000    2f01    0454    0000    0100
0001000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do this by manually creating the header and writing to the file. This post gave me most of what I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8677726/313272